# GraphQL and Github

Tags: github, graphql

I am new to graphQL, hence, I might be doing something wrong or not understanding something fully. I will be more than happy if one can guide me!!!

I am trying to develop a query on graphQL from extracting data from GH.

**Goal:** Extract **author** and **date** (when they last posted on github) from teams groups.

**Done:** I was able to get all the 12 teams' names from one organization and members of every team, but I am having trouble outputting the dates on their last commit discussion, I tried using (updatedAt) but it is not what I am looking for.

Output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "organization": {
      "teams": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "Computer",
              "description": "value.",
              "members": {
                "edges": [
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "name": "W A",
                      "url": "https://github.com/WA"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "name": "V A",
                      "url": "https://github.com/v87"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "name": "A",
                      "url": "https://github.com/A9"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "name": "N F",
                      "url": "https://github.com/NF"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "name": null,
                      "url": "https://github.com/N"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "name": null,
                      "url": "https://github.com/R"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "Leadership Team",
              "description": "leadership positions.",
              "members": {
                "edges": [
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "name": "W S",
                      "url": "https://github.com/WS
                    }
                  },
```

Code:

```
{
  organization(login: "...") {
    teams(first: 20) {
      edges {
        node {
          name
          description
          members {
            edges {
              node {
                name
                url               
                
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```